# Retrieve command doesn't seem to work when trying to access mail from pop3 C#

Tags: c#, pop3

When I connect to pop3.live.com the connection is fine and it also shows me the amount of messages I have and the size of the file but when I try and use "RETR" to get the messages and show them on a console application nothing is presented.

Here is what I have so far

```
 string str = string.Empty;
            string strTemp = string.Empty;
            using (TcpClient tc = new TcpClient())
            {
                tc.Connect("pop3.live.com", 995);
                using (SslStream sl = new SslStream(tc.GetStream()))
                {
                    sl.AuthenticateAsClient("pop3.live.com");
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sl))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sl))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("USER " + _username);
                            sw.Flush();
                            sw.WriteLine("PASS "+ _password);
                            sw.Flush();
                            sw.WriteLine("LIST");
                            sw.Flush();
                            sw.WriteLine("RETR");
                            sw.Flush();
                            sw.WriteLine("QUIT ");
                            sw.Flush();

                            while ((strTemp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (strTemp == "." || strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                str += strTemp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `QUIT` *after* you've finished reading the results? Seems like it might decide not to bother sending results, since you already said "I'm done, goodbye".

Comment: You can make yourself and us a favor, and list the response lines from the server. It is even better if you mix the output and the input in the log. First, it it better for debugging, second, reading everything only after all command is sent is not necessary working, some servers does not support PIPELINING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to use the LIST command, which lists the message numbers. Then issue one or more RETR commands with a single message number from the previous list. Message numbers does not necessarily start from 1! See also my comment on your question about debugging this issue.

For example:

```
LIST
+OK 2 messages (4095)
1 710
2 3385
.
RETR 1
+OK 710 octets
Return-Path: <john@example.com>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

With `RETR`, you need to specify which message to retrieve. `RETR` without a number is not supported per the [POP3 specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt).

Comment: iv tried many functions like that from "RETR 1" "RETR1" "RETR"+1 ect but still nothing